# How can I create a Regex that matches and transforms a period delimited path?

Tags: regex, rename

I am using [den4b Renamer](https://www.den4b.com/products/renamer) to rename a lot of files that follow a specific pattern. The program allows me to use RegEx: (https://www.den4b.com/wiki/ReNamer:Regular_Expressions)

I am stuck trying to conjure up an expression for a specific pattern.

My current RegEx:

```
Expression: ^(com\.)(([\w\s]*\.){0,4})([\w\s]*)$
Replace:    \L$1\L$2\u$4
```

Note: \L and \u transform the sub-expression to upper and lower case as defined in the table below:

[image: Upper and Lower Case Transformations]

Here are a few example strings so you can get an idea of the input:

```
Android File Transfer.svg
Angular Console.svg
Au.Edu.Uq.Esys.Escript.svg
Avidemux.svg
Blackmagic Fusion8.svg
Broken Sword.svg
Browser360 Beta.svg
Btsync GUI.svg
Buttercup Desktop.svg
Calc.svg
Calibre EBook Edit.svg
Calibre Viewer.svg
Call Of Duty.svg
com.GitHub.Plugarut.Pwned Checker.svg
com.GitHub.Plugarut.Wingpanel Monitor.svg
com.GitHub.Rickybas.Date Countdown.svg
com.GitHub.Spheras.Desktopfolder.svg
com.GitHub.Themix Project.Oomox.svg
com.GitHub.Unrud.Remote Touchpad.svg
com.GitHub.Unrud.Video Downloader.svg
com.GitHub.Weclaw1.Image Roll.svg
com.GitHub.Zelikos.Rannum.svg
com.Gitlab.Miridyan.Mt.svg
com.Inventwithpython.Flippy.svg
com.Neatdecisions.Detwinner.svg
com.Rafaelmardojai.Share Preview.svg
com.Rafaelmardojai.Webfont Kit Generator.svg
Distributor Logo Antix.svg
Distributor Logo Archlabs.svg
Distributor Logo Dragonflybsd.svg
DOSBox.svg
Drawio.svg
Drweb GUI.svg
```

For this question I am focused on the strings that begin with `com.xxx.xxx`.

Since I can't *only* target those names in Renamer, the expression has to "play nice" with the other input file names and correctly leave them alone. That's why I've prefixed my expression with `^(com\.)`

What I want:

1. Transform the entire string to lower case except for the last period separated part of the string.
2. Strip white space from the entire string.

For instance:

```
Original:       com.GitHub.Alcadica.Develop.svg
After my Regex: com.github.alcadica.Develop.svg
What I want:    com.github.alcadica.Develop.svg
```

This specific file is correctly renamed. What I'm having trouble with are names that have spaces in any part of the string. I can't figure out how to strip whitespace:

```
Original:       com.Belmoussaoui.Read it Later.svg
After my Regex: com.belmoussaoui.Read it Later.svg
What I want:    com.belmoussaoui.ReaditLater.svg
```

Here is a hypothetical example because I couldn't find a file with more than four parts. I want my pattern to be robust enough to handle this:

```
Original:       com.Shatteredpixel.Another Level.Next.Pixel Dungeon.svg
After my Regex: com.shatteredpixel.another level.next.Pixel Dungeon.svg
What I want:    com.shatteredpixel.anotherlevel.next.PixelDungeon.svg
```

Note that since I'm not using any kind of programming language, I don't have access to common string operations like trim, etc. I can, however, stack expressions. But this would create more overhead and since I am renaming thousands of files at a time I'd ideally like to keep it to one find/replace expression.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I can provide any more information to make this more clear.

**Edit:**

I got it to work with the following rules:

[image: ReNamer]

Really inefficient, but it works. (Thanks to Jeremy in the comments for the idea)

Comment: It seems you will need a second pass. The regex cannot do what you need in one go.

Comment: Then If it's definitely necessary, I am completely open to using two passes. Do you have an example? Really appreciate the help!

Comment: You could try matching the equivalent of alternating matching between whitespace and non-whitespace. Then only include the odd- (or even-) numbered backreferences. Or something hacky like that.

Comment: If this regex engine allows `\G`, use https://regex101.com/r/N0aClF/1

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think global works with Renamer. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Jeremy can you give a simple example? I'm not sure how I would structure that.

Comment: Then there is no way with this tool. Use PS on Windows/Linux tools

Comment: I got it to work. Updated the post. Thank you @Jeremy for the inspiration!

Comment: A two pass idea... Pass 1 / strip spaces: [Search for `^(com\.|.+)|[\t ]+` and replace with `$1`](https://regex101.com/r/Ce73nm/1) Pass 2 / Upper to lower: [Search for `^(com\.|.+)|(\b\w+\.\w+)$|([A-Z])` and replace with `$1$2\L$3`](https://regex101.com/r/O2KNmn/1) (no idea if this works in your tool)